# Broken function/logical vector-r

Tags: r, for-loop

```
num_only <- function(df) {

for (clm in seq_along(df)) {
  num_cols <- vector("logical", length = ncol(df))
  num_cols[[clm]] <-ifelse(length(grep('[aA-zZ]', df[[clm]])) == 0, TRUE, 
FALSE) 

}
  return(num_cols)
}
```

The above function is supposed to return a logical vector that tells me if the column in a data frame has only numeric characters.  However, it seems to return an incorrect value when I run it for the first column (maybe even the first two).

```
mydf <- data.frame(new = letters[11:20], 
               a = rnorm(10), 
               b = letters[1:10], 
               c = LETTERS[1:10], 
               d = rnorm(10))
```

When I enter the above df, it should return a logical vector of FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE, but I get this:

```
num_only(mydf)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

I'm not sure what's wrong.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want `ifelse` since you are testing only one logical value at a time. And the return vector should be created outside the `for` loop.
Also, there's a much simpler and `R-ish` solution, that is not equivalent, but determines whether a column is of class `numeric` or not. Maybe you're interessted.

```
num_only <- function(df) {
    num_cols <- vector("logical", length = ncol(df))
    for (clm in seq_along(df)) {
        num_cols[[clm]] <-if(length(grep('[A-Za-z]', df[[clm]])) == 0)
            TRUE
        else
            FALSE
    }
    return(num_cols)
}

num_only2 <- function(df) unname(sapply(df, is.numeric))

num_only(mydf)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

num_only2(mydf)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this.  I thought about your second function except that the df columns are all character classes, so I didn't think is.numeric would work